# Why do we care about the Champernowne constant?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, constants

I was browsing code golf and I came across this challenge:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68685/the-rien-number

It caught my interest and I wanted to learn a bit more about the Champernowne constant. I did some very brief googling and I can't seem to find what's the significance of this constant.

With that said, why (do we)/(should we) care about this constant?

Comment: An example of a number normal in base 10. Apart from that...

Comment: We don't. There's nothing interesting about it.

Comment: Good enough for me.